# How do you reference other modules from the Flask application factory in a blueprint?

Tags: python, flask

My amateur coding brain is trying to work with Flask. I'd like to have a second database connection available throughout for various queries (I don't want to use an ORM for these queries). In my `__init__.py` file I have this code...

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    db = dbase.Database()
    ...
```

Given this, in a blueprint, how can I access the `db` object to execute queries and other data related things?

For example, in my `main` Blueprint on the homepage I might try this...

```
@main.route('/')
@login_required
def home():
    other_data = db.connection.execute('QUERY GOES HERE')
    return render_template('home.html', data=other_data)
```

I've tried to reference the `db` object all sorts of ways with various import approaches, but I'm running into walls. Any help is appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create shareable module and later you can use that module anywhere you like.

Example:

```
# extensions.py

db = dbase.Database()


# app2/routes.py

from extensions import db
from . import app2

@app2.route('/somewhere/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def somewhere():
    data = db.q........
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing here. Thank you!